# Get class name (KendoUI)

Tags: kendo-ui

How can I get class name for some instance?

```
var Animal = kendo.Class.extend({
    getClassName: function() {
        console.log(????); //to get Animal
    }
});
```

I already try this.constructor.name and it is an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can't. 
If you're talking about widgets, they store their name in `this.options.name`.

`Function.name` is experimental ES6 and it doesn't really help anyway because `Class.extend` returns an anonymous function, so it doesn't have a name.

So you'll just have to find another way to do this, e.g. by passing it in:

```
var Animal = kendo.Class.extend({
    name: "Animal",
    getClassName: function() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
});
```